# Cannot import packages, like pandas & numpy, using Spyder 5 installed under Conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

OS: Win 11
Python: 3.9
Spyder version: 4 & 5

1. I created a Conda environment with

   *>> conda create -n tensorflow2.x*
2. Then I activated the environment with

   *>> activate tensorflow2.x*
3. Within the created environment, I could sucessfully import packages like numpy and pandas without any errors:

   *>> python*

   *>> import numpy*

   *>> import pandas*
4. However, when I installed spyder in my created environment, and still used the same way as step 3, it reported an error that "No module named Numpy/Pandas".

   *>> pip install spyder*

Any ideas about this? If I remember correctly, I used to do the same thing on Ubuntu os. And the installed Spyder ran normally. Not sure what is wrong with my operations on Win 11 os.

Comment: Sounds like they are looking at different Python installations, or environments.  Aside, generally mixing `pip` and `conda` will have unexpected / negative side effects. Stick with one or the other, not both.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use conda install only, and it seems that the problem was still there T_T Actually, I think, with "conda create -n <env_name>", the created environment inherits all the packages from the base environment. While after installing spyder within the environment, it seems that these packages are not inherited anymore. Seems that the installation of Spyder re-stipulate the environment path I guess? Anyway, alternatively, I can manually re-install all packages I need to use.

Comment: A new environment is created with minimal packages (unless you clone an environment). Therefore, ensure the environment is *activated* **before** installing new packages. If the env is active, then `conda install <pkg>` is run, the package will be installed to the active env. Then, make sure Spyder is looking at the 'correct' env, and all should be well.  Alternatively, consider using `virtualenv`, then drop Anaconda all together, and use `pip` for everything -- this is much more straight-forward (IMO) and flexible, as you no longer need to rely on conda channels; it 'just works'.

Comment: Link here: [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/)